# Как построить фильтры?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, reactjs, redux, filter

Привет!

У меня есть больше количество фильтров и элементов. Мне нужно выводить только те элементы которые подходят по фильтрам.

Писать if или что-то подобно на каждый элемент не хочу, лень. )

Как бы вы решили такую задачу? Хочу найти максимально короткое, простое, гибкое и интуитивно понятное решение.

Пишу на React + Redux.

Comment: Здорова! Пример бы Вашего кода посмотреть, где Вы планируете много-много `if` использовать

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы получаете все элементы и фильтруете их на клиенте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так, всего лишь 1 `if`

```
var filtr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var elem = [
{
    "fgfg": 0,
    "jfjf":3
},
{
    "fgfg": 0,
    "jfjf":4
},
{
    "fgfg": 0,
    "jfjf":0
}
]

for (var i=0; i<filtr.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<elem.length; j++) {
        for (var t in elem[j]){
            if (elem[j][t] == filtr[i]) {
                console.log(elem[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```